# A lot of people take taxi to visit relatives and friends' houses

Tags: grammar, possessives, plural-forms

It's always confusing when 2 nouns join together, and there's another noun before it. Which noun shall we put the "s", for the plural form, or both?

> A lot of people take taxi to visit relatives and friends'  houses.

Relative, friend, house, which one to put "s"?

Comment: If you really want to only modify apostrophe locations, I'd put apostrophes on both "relatives" and "friends," but if you give me more freedom, I'd delete the apostrophe, delete "houses' (so just visit relatives and friends), and add "a" before "taxi."

Comment: It depends if each house belongs to both relatives and friends, or some houses belong to relatives and others to friends.

Comment: It's not the houses you are visiting, but the people in them.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the given example:

> (1) A lot of people take taxi to visit relatives and friends' houses.

The words "*friends*" and  "*relatives*" should be treated in the same way. Either both should be possessives, or neither. The words "*taxi"* should have an indefinite article, or else it should be plural. Some possible versions:

> (2) A lot of people take taxis to visit relatives' and friends' houses.
> (3) A lot of people take a taxi to visit relatives' and friends' houses.
> (4) A lot of people take a taxi to visit relatives and friends.
> (5) A lot of people take taxis to visit relatives and friends.

Remember that "s" usually makes a noun plural, file "s'" generally makes it both plural and possessive. since "a lot of people" is a plural construct, it is probably best to use the plural form "taxis". But one may instead use "a taxi" to indicate that this is a typical situation, each person takes a single taxi. One may use a singular noun with a collective phrase in this way, and fluent speakers often do so. But one should not say or write "*take taxi*" in the singualr with no article.